# Android - gradle.properties windows

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need to put some signing variables into gradle and 
in mac you can put it in

`HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties`

but what about windows?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In Windows you can use this file:

```
C:\Users\username\.gradle\gradle.properties
```

Comment: Its not there in that location

Comment: @SachinHR just create the file in that folder.